# how to get a notification when there is a new post [ruby on rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Any one know how to create a notification Pop up in ruby on rails.
I have a ruby Application where i want when any admin posted a new article it should get pop up when the other users automaticlly , and when they aren't online it should also appear when they log in to the application

Answer (score 0):

Using an [observer](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/19-use-observer) or use an [after_save callback](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save). Do be aware that if you choose the callback method, the return value will be ignored. An example of an observer follows:

```
# in your model class
  after_save :send_create_notifications

  private
    def send_create_notifications
       users.notifications << model
    end
```

And the callback version:

```
# No indication of the callback's existence in your model class
class NotificationObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe MyModel

  def after_create(model)
     users.notifications << model
  end
end
```